Significance of Caspian's name?
Caspian is perhaps the most important Narnian character in the series (meaning someone who was born and lived their whole life in Narnia, so neither Aslan nor the eight Seven Friends of Narnia count). He's the only character whose name appears in the title of one of the seven books, and he's a major character in two books and a background character in a third.
What is the significance, if any, of the name "Caspian"? As a child I was excited to learn that there was a real sea with the same name as him; now I wonder if he was named after the sea for some particular reason. Other character names (notably Aslan and Jadis) have Turkic origins; is Caspian another such case?

I think Lewis just liked names on maps.  That's where he got "Narnia" (Latin name of the Italian city of Narni), after all.

Where is your own research? How far did you get before hitting what barrier?

One possibility is a connection with silver. The Akkadian for silver is kaspum, which has several cognates in other languages.
